# Problem with ROSARIA rostopic info

Tags: ros-fuerte, rosaria, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently installed ROS Fuerte on a new machine, and I am having trouble installing the ROSARIA package for Pioneer series robots. Specifically, I think that a URL on the ROS side is set wrong, or is not providing useful content. I get the following error when I enter rostopic info ROSARIA:

```
$ roslocate info ROSARIA
error contacting http__://ros.org/doc/api/ROSARIA/stack.yaml:
HTTP Error 404: Not Found
error contacting http__://ros.org/doc/api/ROSARIA/manifest.yaml:
HTTP Error 404: Not Found
cannot locate information about ROSARIA
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57814/problem-with-rosaria-rostopic-info/) by [Sven Kratz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4398/sven-kratz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2013-03-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed ROSARIA manually by checking out the repository from Google code :

```
cd ~/ros
rosws set amor-ros-pkg https___://code.google.com/p/amor-ros-pkg/ --hg
```

Make sure to update to revision 30 only, as the later revisions are broken and do not compile when calling :

```
rosmake ROSARIA
```

---

Originally posted by [Sven Kratz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4398/sven-kratz/) with karma: 26 on 2013-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0